# Eisenstein's criterion for polynomials in Z mod p

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I know that Eisenstein criterion is sufficient condition to determine whether a polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb Q$.

But I do not know if the same approach can be applied to a body such $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

For example the polynomial:

$x^5+2x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+2  \in \mathbb{Z}_{3}[x]$

with $p = 2$

Eisenstein criterion would say that it is irreducible.

Comment: Unlike $\Bbb Z$, the ring $\Bbb F_p$ is a field. Every nonzero element is a unit, just like $\pm1$ in $\Bbb Z$. For instance, with your polynomial, the last constant is $2$, which is invertible mod $3$. As Wikipedia notes, the criterion generalizes to prime ideals and integral domains (as the proof needn't assume any less), but you need to understand there are no nonzero nonunits in fields so the criterion won't work in $k[x]$ when $k$ is a field.